# How to synchronize concurring Web Service calls in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, persistence

I'm currently developing some web services in Java (& JPA with MySQL connection) that are being triggered by an SAP System.
To simplify my problem I'm referring the two crucial entities as `BlogEntry` and `Comment`. A `BlogEntry` can have multiple `Comments`. A `Comment` always belongs to exactly one `BlogEntry`.

So I have three Services (which I can't and don't want to redefine, since they're defined by the WSDL I exported from SAP and used parallel to communicate with other Systems): `CreateBlogEntry`, `CreateComment`, `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry`

They are being properly triggered and there's absolutely no problem with `CreateBlogEntry` or `CreateComment` when they're called seperately.

**But:** The service `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry` sends the `Comment` and a "foreign key" to identify the "upcoming" `BlogEntry`. Internally it also calls `CreateBlogEntry` to create the actual `BlogEntry`. **These two services are - due to their asynchronous nature - concurring.**

So I have two options:

1. create a dummy `BlogEntry` and connect the `Comment` to it & update the `BlogEntry`, once `CreateBlogEntry` "arrives"
2. wait for `CreateBlogEntry` and connect the `Comment` afterwards to the new `BlogEntry`

Currently I'm trying the **former** but once both services are fully executed, I end up with **two** `BlogEntries`. One of them only has the `ID` delivered by `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry` but it is properly connected to the `Comment` (more the other way round). The other `BlogEntry` has all the other information (such as `postDate` or `body`), but the `Comment` isn't connected to it.

---

Here's the code snippet of the service implementation `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry`:

```
@EJB
private BlogEntryFacade blogEntryFacade;
@EJB
private CommentFacade commentFacade;
...
List<BlogEntry> blogEntries = blogEntryFacade.findById(request.getComment().getBlogEntryId().getValue());
BlogEntry persistBlogEntry;
if (blogEntries.isEmpty()) {
    persistBlogEntry = new BlogEntry();
    persistBlogEntry.setId(request.getComment().getBlogEntryId().getValue());
    blogEntryFacade.create(persistBlogEntry);
} else {
    persistBlogEntry = blogEntries.get(0);
}

Comment persistComment = new Comment();
persistComment.setId(request.getComment().getID().getValue());
persistComment.setBody(request.getComment().getBody().getValue());
/*
    set other properties
*/
persistComment.setBlogEntry(persistBlogEntry);
commentFacade.create(persistComment);
...
```

---

And here's the code snippet of the implementation `CreateBlogEntry`:

```
@EJB
private BlogEntryFacade blogEntryFacade;
...
List<BlogEntry> blogEntries = blogEntryFacade.findById(request.getBlogEntry().getId().getValue());
BlogEntry persistBlogEntry;
Boolean update = false;
if (blogEntries.isEmpty()) {
    persistBlogEntry = new BlogEntry();
} else {
    persistBlogEntry = blogEntries.get(0);
    update = true;
}
persistBlogEntry.setId(request.getBlogEntry().getId().getValue());
persistBlogEntry.setBody(request.getBlogEntry().getBody().getValue());
/*
    set other properties
*/
if (update) {
    blogEntryFacade.edit(persistBlogEntry);
} else {
    blogEntryFacade.create(persistBlogEntry);
}
...
```

This is some fiddling that fails to make things happen as supposed.

Sadly I haven't found a method to synchronize these simultaneous service calls. I could let the `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry` *sleep* for a few seconds but I don't think that's the proper way to do it.

Can I force each instance of my `facades` and their respective `EntityManagers` to reload their datasets? Can I put my requests in some sort of queue that is being emptied based on certain conditions?

***So: What's the best pracice to make it wait for the `BlogEntry` to exist?***

Thanks in advance,
David

Info:

- GlassFish Server 3.1.2
- EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461

Comment: Why don't you check in `CreateBlogEntry` if a blog entry with the same id (and created by `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry`) already exists ? If yes, update rather create.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently trying to do (see the second code snippet).

Comment: Mea Culpa. Strange you are getting two entries (with the same unique Id?)

Comment: I may have to say that the ID refers to a value generated by the issuing SAP system and isn't really called ID, the database has its own set of primary keys (real unique IDs).
I have now managed to make my code run properly by telling the `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry`-Thread to sleep 10 seconds and clearing the EntityManger's cache by calling         `getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` in my `facade`.
I still refuse to believe that's the best solution :(

Comment: In other words `blogEntryFacade.edit(persistBlogEntry);`fails to update the current record bu creates a new one ? Sounds pretty buggy.  Are you sure your persistence policy is OK?

Comment: The problem is that both calls to `blogEntryFacade.findById(...);` happen almost simultaneously before any `BlogEntry` is created at all (so both lists are empty and each thread creates a new `BlogEntry`).

Thus `blogEntryFacade.edit(persistBlogEntry);` is never called.
I have now implemented a sleep-loop that rechecks every second for a matching `BlogEntry` (which is created, once `CreateBlogEntry` comes in) and exits if a certain time limit is reached. It works but I still don't think that's a neat solution :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you are getting a `CreateBlogEntry` call, queue the `CreateCommentForUpcomingBlogEntry` calls and dequeue and process them once you receive the `CreateBlogEntry` call.

Since you are on an application server, for queues, you can probably use JMS queues that autoflush to storage or use the DB cache engine (Ehcache ?), in case you receive a lot of calls or want to provide a recovery mechanism across restarts.